# EF Core logical query

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, entity-framework-core

I have C# project which uses EF Core with MVC.

I have a controller representing a "virtual" entity. This entity is created by selecting from two different tables, aggregate each one of them by month and year, and then connecting the two results.

My question is: is it possible (and if so, is it a good solution) to make this sums with EF Core? Or should I just iterate through the elements with C# and aggregate them the way I want?

**EDIT**: Currently I'm up to this:

```
 public IEnumerable<MyTable> Get...(int month, int year)
        return _context.MyTable
           //.Include(b => b.)
           .Where(t => t.Month == month && t.Year == year)
           .GroupBy(a => a.BrokerId)
           .Select(param1 => new {
                                   BrokerId = param1.Key,
                                   TotalCommissionAmountBruto = param1.Sum(s => s.CommissionAmountBruto),
                                   TotalCommissionAmountNeto = param1.Sum(s=>s.CommissionAmountNeto)
                       });
```

This throws an error because the result from the query is not formatted as `MyTable` object. I've tried creating another viewModel for the result, but with no success(same error about implicit casting)

The viewModel :

```
public class MyViewModel : DtoBase
{
    public int brokerId { get; set; }
    public int TotalCommissionAmountBruto { get; set; }
    public int TotalCommissionAmountNeto { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: How are the tables related to each other?

Comment: Month, Year and brokerID

Comment: You can use join and select

Comment: From what I understand you want to create a *Business* object which is generated from different *Data model* objects with various joins and aggregates. What I would do is define a business class, and create a Service method that handle the queries (with EF queries) and return your business object(s).
You could also do that at the Database level with views or stored procedure, and setup EF to be aware of these, and make EF calls to these views or stored procuedure.

Comment: EF is quite capable of generating the requests with joins and so on, using LINQ (though EF Core is still much more limited)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Edit based on code now shown in question:**

Your select as shown is returning an anonymous type:

```
.Select(param1 => new {
                         BrokerId = param1.Key,
                         TotalCommissionAmountBruto = param1.Sum(s => s.CommissionAmountBruto),
                         TotalCommissionAmountNeto = param1.Sum(s=>s.CommissionAmountNeto)
                       });
```

Return your view model and you should be set:

```
.Select(param1 => new MyViewModel {
                                    BrokerId = param1.Key,
                                    TotalCommissionAmountBruto = param1.Sum(s => s.CommissionAmountBruto),
                                    TotalCommissionAmountNeto = param1.Sum(s=>s.CommissionAmountNeto)
                       });
```

Then change your return type on the Action from:

```
public IEnumerable<MyTable> Get...(int month, int year)
```

to

```
public IEnumerable<MyViewModel> Get...(int month, int year)
```

Then in your view you'll also have to change the model to use the new view model.

Bonus -

You should consider returning a view model instead of directly returning your database model to the view.  View Models have many benefits:

Protects against mass assignment vulnerability (the ability to post more than you intended the user to post). See

- https://odetocode.com/blogs/scott/archive/2012/03/11/complete-guide-to-mass-assignment-in-asp-net-mvc.aspx
- [https://andrewlock.net/preventing-mass-assignment-or-over-posting-in-asp-net-core/]
- [2https://www.hanselman.com/blog/ASPNETOverpostingMassAssignmentModelBindingSecurity.aspx

They can be tailored for each view allowing for things like logic for the view to be implemented that isn't in the database model or is specific to this view only.

They promote loose coupling to allow the view to change for different needs than the database model.

**Original answer before questioner added edit to show code:**

You can use group by and aggregate functions in EF Core.  Take a look at the LINQ GroupBy sample in [these docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/what-is-new/ef-core-2.1) for a basic example.  It can get a lot more complicated than the sample shows.

```
var query = context.Orders
    .GroupBy(o => new { o.CustomerId, o.EmployeeId })
    .Select(g => new
        {
          g.Key.CustomerId,
          g.Key.EmployeeId,
          Sum = g.Sum(o => o.Amount),
          Min = g.Min(o => o.Amount),
          Max = g.Max(o => o.Amount),
          Avg = g.Average(o => Amount)
        });
```

Above is the basic idea of grouping by and then using some of the aggregate functions.

If you have the SQL written for it and prefer to use it you can also have [EF Core call raw SQL](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/raw-sql) which at first might seem too limiting in that you have to have the result map to an entity (and your case you don't).  In 2.1 they added mapping to your [own defined model](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/query-types) (your virtual entity, View Model) called [query types](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/mt847184.aspx) and defining query.

In 2.1 you could create a view model (what you are calling virtual entity), add it to your EF Context and then you can query against it with a database view, another EF query ([defining query](http://thedatafarm.com/data-access/defining-a-defining-query-in-ef-core-2-1/)) and/or anonymous types (with limitations).

For example:

Given a view model:

```
public class MySpecialModel
{  
  public string Name { get; private set; }
  public int Count { get; private set; }
}
```

You would add it to your context:

```
public DbQuery<MySpecialModel> MySpecialModel {get;set;}
```

Then you would call it:

```
var results = context.MySpecialModel.FromSql("select name,count from a join b on b.id=a.id)
```

If for some reason this doesn't work or is too limiting, I recommend using a micro ORM like [dapper](https://stackexchange.github.io/Dapper/) that can take your raw SQL and map it to a model.

Your more nuanced question of is it good to?

Short answer - probably but always check your ORMS resultant SQL and adjust accordingly to your needs.

Longer answer - Without knowing the complexity of the query or your existing EF Core logic and the resultant SQL it generates AND your context, how performant does it have to be, how many users, how often will it be called, etc..., we are not able to answer this.

Comment: I'm just in the middle of using the first way you suggested, I've encountered an error, I'm selecting the data in a method , and I need to know the data type it returns .. (In your example I'm referring to `query`) It throws "Cannot implicitly convert..." which makes sense , but which type should I return from the method ? I don't want to return `IENumerable<Object>` as I want to be more specific. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Have you created a view model?  The sample is returning an anonymous type (.Select(g=> new....  vs. (.Select(g=> new MyViewModel....  I can't easily answer what is going wrong with what you have given.  Your question is essentially another question.  If you are trying to construct a query with EF Core and are running into an issue it would be better to ask another SO question with the exact Query syntax and the exact error and the desired result you are looking for.  Then we could help you out better.... :-)

Comment: I've updated my question with extra data.. if it's still not enough I'll open another question tomorrow :)

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways to achieve this requirement. If there is a parent-child relationship between the tables you can use `Include` and `ThenInclude`.

You can run the stored procedure also using `FromSql` method and select the required data.

You can also use projection query using `Select` extension method.

You can refer to the official documentation provided by Microsoft for all of the above.